# Store WebSocket data in mysql

Tags: mysql, websocket

How to store data received through websocket connection to MySql if websocket data is coming in faster than my sql insert or update queries are executed?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Mongo DB for that.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain the benefits of using MongoDB?